# OnItemClick how to get text value of clicked item from list view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I want to get the text value of a list item and pass it to an edit text in another fragment when list item is clicked.

Here is my code to get the value and pass it to the other fragment.

```
    lv_categories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String clickedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim();
            SM.sendData(clickedItem);
        }
    });
```

send data method

```
@Override
public void sendData(String message) {
    String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.container + ":" + 1;
    SearchFragment searchFragment = (SearchFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    searchFragment.displayReceivedData(message);
}
```

I am able to receive the data but not as is displayed eg. Instead of receiving the list item "Christmas", I am getting something like "com.example.johndoe.project.Category@fa9dc73"

Also how am I able to change fragments on click?

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: share you model class that you passes in listview with question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363151/getting-the-values-of-listview-selected-item/47363188#47363188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am able to receive the data but not as is displayed eg. Instead of receiving the list item "Christmas", I am getting something like "com.example.johndoe.project.Category@fa9dc73"

Because **`adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)`** Might Returning you custom Model class not  **`String`** value

Try this

```
lv_categories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                YourModelClass data = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

                SM.sendData(data.getMessage);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

--> `adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)` not a String!

So replace,-------

```
String clickedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim();
```

with,

```
String clickedItem = ((Category)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getMyTextproperty();
```

it is good if you can share your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Your converting `class` to `string` which obviously prints `classname` with offset, try below

```
lv_categories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String clickedItem = ((Category)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).getMyTextproperty();
            SM.sendData(clickedItem);
        }
    });
```